# Preserving the right order in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `$array_one` with following data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [postId] => 412812
            [shortcode] => 4sF9
         )
)
```

There are lots of data with more keys.

Now the problem is `array_one` changes its order every now and then. For example, it will make key `7` to key `0` and push everything else down, without having new data.

What I wanna do is display everything in array, but do not change its order when it changes it order, so my display of post will have static post order.

I tried to create another array with following logic:

1. Declare new empty array called `$array_two`.
2. Create a function that check if `array_two` has everything as `array_one` (used: `in_array()`). For the first time, its a no, because `array_two` is initially empty.
3. Next step is, if `array_one` does not have everything as `array_two` then copy everything from `array_one` to `array_two` and display `array_two` (used: `array_push()`).
4. At this point, `array_two` will be same as `array_one`.

I had other conditions that says, if not all the post for `array_one` is not same as `array_two` then only get a unique post from `array_one` and put it in `array_two` everything else remains same in `array_two`.

Now the problem is, after `array_two` preserves everything from `array_one`, it start over with empty `array_two`.

I just cannot think of anything where declaration of `array_two` will be run only once. In other words, how can I achieve this so every time page refreshes it does not start over.

**Edited:** array_one is getting data through an API which changes its order, and the method is being used is `json_decode($result)`

I hope I have made myself clear, now.

Comment: What is the reason that `$array_one` it's order of keys changes? That might be the key to solving your problem. You might also want to store your array into `$_SESSION` so you check it's structure/order again on another page.

Comment: Are you parsing this from json? javascript associative arrays do **not** have a guaranteed order. Also, I think you should be using `json_decode($string, true);` rather than `json_decode($string);`. This makes the hash a hash, rather than an Object.

Comment: are you pulling the data from a database? because you can sort it in your query if you are

Comment: I don't really follow your question here. Array don't just reorder themselves without you performing operations on them to modify them. You might consider showing specific code examples along with var_dumps to better illustrate the problem you are having.  Also it sounds like at the end you are asking about how to persist data across page reloads.  There are a number of ways to do this, but it is not clear if this data is specific to each user session (in which case session data storage might make sense), or if this is general to all users (in which some form of caching might make sense).

Comment: This is a clear use case for sessions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have mentioned that array_one is getting all the data through an API. API changes order of the post and I get exactly what and how API sends it. I have never worked with sessions before, how can I achieve this through sessions ? @JoeFrambach yes it's json_decode($result). Let me know if you guys have more questions.